# python pyttsx3 error -- _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech, pyttsx

i am trying to convert text to speech using **pyttsx3** in **python**. but iam getting the error -- **_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.**
it worked once. later it didn't

my code

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

error i am receiving is --

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py",
>   line 20, in init

```
eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
```

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in
>   **getitem**

```
o = self.data[key]()
```

> KeyError: None
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ...
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 113, in _LoadDicts

```
version = p.load()
```

> _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.

python version is **3.7.3** |
pyttsx3 version is **2.71**|
pywin32 version is **224**

**please help**

Comment: You should edit the question for additional information, not add it in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem as well and fixed it by deleting gen_py in my temp directory.

You can find this folder here:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not access the folder through windows. So, I used DOS, located the exact path and renamed the folder.